# Unity: Catch exception thrown during Awake()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, error-handling

I have a Unity project where I'm dynamically instantiating a prefab, and that prefab has a custom script component that further initializes the component during the Awake() function. At this point initizalization might fail and need to be aborted, which means that both the current game object needs to be destroyed, and the called needs to be notified in some way. While destroying the game object is no problem, elegantly notifying the caller is proving more difficult.

The exception thrown by the instance appears in the Unity Console, where the stack trace of the exception also includes the Instantiate call, but attempting to catch any exception on the line with the Instantiate call does nothing.

How can I catch an exception at that point in the caller, or otherwise use built-in functionality to signal that initialization needs to be aborted?

P.S.
I Know I could let the instance set a flag and inspect that from the caller, or first let Unity handle initialization of the game object, and handle my initialization in a direct call and catch an error there, but I was hoping a nicer solution is possible.

Comment: Why would you catch this rather than fixing the underlying issue though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Instantiate` method catches exceptions internally, so that you cannot catch any exceptions outside, you must catch them inside the `Awake` message and then use the `DestroyImmediate` method to destroy the instance immediately.

```
void Awake()
{
    try
    {
        throw new System.Exception();
    }
    catch
    {
        DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
    }
}
```

By using this method, the `Instantiate` method can throw a `UnityException` which you are able to catch.

```
try
{
    Instantiate(prefab);
}
catch(UnityException)
{
    print("Instantiate prefab failed");
}
```